# How to calculate a persistent property based on transient property before persist?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transient

Say I have a persistent property `A` in an entity, and 2 transient fields `T1`, `T2`. When the entity is persisted, I need to calculate `A` based on `T1`, `T2` (suppose this is a legacy database which can not be altered).

```
@Entity
Class MyEntity {
    @Column(name="persistantA")
    Integer A;

    @Transient
    Integer T1;

    @Transient
    Integer T2;

    @PrePersist
    void prePersist() {
        A = T1 * T2;
    }
}
```

However inside the `prePersist()` method all transient fields are cleared --- they are set to their initial value --- and this seems to be the proper behavior for Hibernate/Jpa.

How to overcome this?

I am using Spring boot with Jpa and Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

If you persist a new entity by calling `EntityManager::persist`, then the behaviour you describe will not happen and transient fields will be visible in the `@PrePersist` method.

However, if you persist a new entity with `EntityManager::merge`, then the merging mechanism will ignore transient fields, which is expected behaviour - only the properties that Hibernate is aware of are merged. Keep in mind that `merge` always returns a copy (except when the argument is already a managed instance), so you have to copy transient fields manually into the result of the `merge` operation.

Comment: You are right. However I wants to perform the transformation for both persit() and merget(). I solved this problem by calling the transform function in the setter method at last.